# Batch File to retrieve Local Area Connection Name in Windows XP

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, lan

I'm currently writing a simple batch script to set the DNS of a LAN connection automatically. Here is the script:

```
REM Set DNS 
netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" static X.X.X.X
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" Y.Y.Y.Y index=2
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" Z.Z.Z.Z index=3
```

But the thing is, if the Local Area Network name is not default (i.e. Local Area Connection), the script will not work.

Is there any way I can detect all the Local Area Connection names and set all of those LAN connections' DNS using the batch file?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've tested this code in *Windows 7*.  You may need to make some modifications for *Windows XP*.

```
@Echo Off
For /f "skip=2 tokens=4*" %%a In ('NetSh Interface IPv4 Show Interfaces') Do (
    Call :UseNetworkAdapter %%a "%%b"
)
Exit /B

:UseNetworkAdapter
:: %1 = State
:: %2 = Name (quoted); %~2 = Name (unquoted)
If %1==connected (
    :: Do your stuff here, for example:
    Echo %2
)
Exit /B
```

I'll just note that I always use `Call` statements rather than bracketed script.  Too often people become confused when environment variables don't behave as expected in bracketed script.  I find calling a label makes script easier to work with.

**EDIT:** Explination.

The [`For`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) command reads each line of a file or command result.
`In ('command')` tells it to read each line of the results of `command`.
`skip=2` skips the first two lines of output, in this case, the column header.
`tokens=4*` says to read the fourth thing on each line as one variable (`4`), and everything after that as another variable (`*`).
`%%a` says to store the above tokens in `%%a` and `%%b` respectively.
`Do (commands)` executes the `commands` for each line.

My output of `NetSh Interface IPv4 Show Interface` is:

```
Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 15          50        1500  disconnected  Bluetooth Network Connection
 24          10        1500  connected     Network Bridge
```

So I take the fourth token (the State) and all tokens after that (the Name) and pass them to a script function call.  Here they are retrieved as command line parameters, namely `%1` and `%2`.
Note that each Name consists of two or three tokens because of the spaces, hence using `*` instead of `5`.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your help :) However, I am a newbie in batch scripts (although I have programming knowledge). Can you please explain to be what is going on in the script? Btw, in Windows XP, I use "netsh interface ip show address" to get a list of the names and the ip/subnet/mask information of each network connection

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get any XP computers here to run `NetSh Interface IP Show Interface`.  See my answer for an explination of the script.

Comment: thanks a lot..i get the idea and i will try to adjust for windows xp :)

Comment: For XP adjust Hand-E-Food code:  you must type "netsh interface ip" instead of "netsh interface ipv4 ...". Another problem is even though the code runs without error on XP, it will not display any connection/interface information. This might have to do with remote access service though.

Comment: I used @Hand-E-Food code but it doesn't display anything. I had to use skip=3 and then I get my first interface displayed (loopback). However the following ones are not displayed. Any idea why? I'm using Win7 and `NetSh Interface IP Show Interface` show 5 interfaces (3 of them are "connected")

Comment: @remyremy, maybe the interface you want is running on IPv6.  Try `NetSh Interface IPv6 Show Interface` instead.  Play around with the `NetSh` command to find the data you need before worrying about the script.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP 1st line output of command 'netsh int ip show config' is:

> Configuration for interface "Local Area Connection"

```
@echo off
for /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%a in ('netsh int ip show config') do set "sUserFriendyName=%%a"
echo/set http://www.opendns.com/ DNS for interface "%sUserFriendyName%"
netsh int ip delete dns "%sUserFriendyName%" all
netsh interface ip set dns name="%sUserFriendyName%" source=static addr=208.67.222.222 register=PRIMARY
netsh interface ip add dns name="%sUserFriendyName%" addr=208.67.220.220 index=2
ipconfig /flushdns
```